# How to connect PostgreSQL with Spring Mvc

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, spring-mvc

I want to set up the database connection on Spring MVC with PostgreSQL, how do I do it?
I have tried  google search but still, I have not found what I am looking for, so far I have added a PostgreSQL dependency on my project and here are the codes

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
  </dependency>
```

So where do I go from here?
how do I create the configuration files for db?
What is the default login credentials for db?
Where do I see the database table?

Comment: Are you using spring boot ? Give us more details.

Comment: Am using  Spring MVC framework with maven project on eclipse neon

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your database connection. You can create a classe  to configure this. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {

    DriverManagerDataSource bds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    bds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Drive");
    bds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:5432/dbname");
    bds.setUsername("user");
    bds.setPassword("pass");

    return bds;
}
```

}

And then, you can inject the datasource in your bens.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;
}
```

Try to use Spring boot with spring data. Is very simple to configure a database connection and create repositories for data manipulations (CRUD). See this https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Thanks for reply @Mychell the thing is am new to spring frameworks and the professor directed us to use Spring MVC on this project, sorry for my lame questions  but i would love to know where do i create database name, what are the default login for PostegreSql db? If i were to use Mysql i would go to phpmyadmin and create the db name where do  i go for this on PostgreSql?

Comment: You should use pgadmin. It is a Open Source administration and development platform for PostgreSQL like phpmyadmin to Mysql.  During the postgresql instalation your define the postgres use password. So, you can use to create the database.